# iCarousel type linear, breaks UI

Tags: icarousel

When I use iCarousel type linear, and wrap is true. I am getting an UI like below:[image]

The problem, I am facing is at the top the number 998 UI is broken, but I want visible 998 number without increasing iCarousel height. So, how can I achieve this? and one more thing I don't bother about UI might break for number 2, if I want a visible 998 number.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why your carousel item is cut off:

1) Your carousel view is not vertically centered in the window. If you center it, 0 will be dead centre and 998 and 2 will both be cut off, but equally

2) You need to set the item view size to exactly fit your view. You're currently using the default images that come with the example project which are 200x200 pixels in size. Presumably you will eventually replace these with your own views. When you do, make sure the size of those views is an exact division of the height of your window, so for example if your windows is 1024 pixels high, and you want to show 5 views, then they need to be 1024/5 pixels high (204.8 px). Obviously that's not a nice number, but you can make them a bit smaller so that they are a nice round number and then adding some spacing between them using the carousel delegate method.

Comment: Thanks Nick... Whether it is possible to achieve, no. 2 to be cut off but not the no.998

Comment: just move your carousel view down

Comment: Nick, r u saying carousel view frame move down?

Comment: yes. move the top of the iCarousel view frame down until the item view lines up with the top of your window.

Comment: if you don't want to resize your carousel view for some reason, you can get the same effect by moving the contentOffset property down instead (it's a CGPoint).